# How can I substitute for live keyboard sound?

Tags: recording, live-sound

Im trying to figure out how can I get the keyboard/piano line for my live music when my keyboard player is absent?  Durms and guitar/bass are always there.  What can I do?

Comment: It's not exactly easy to understand what you're asking here, might be a good idea to rephrase / expand.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options:

- make charts of the keyboard part and find a substitute player for the gig
- record the keyboard parts and have a playback device that you can send into the PA or an amp.

Finding a sub that can play the charts can be difficult, and may require additional rehearsals, or clean charts and a competent player. Their pay may be higher than what the band members normally get also.

Playing to a recording can be an issue in a live show as it is difficult to reset the groove if the band starts to drift. That being said, I know two different bands that use a laptop on stage to play additional parts. The bands rehearse with the parts and their drummers are good so they don't have any issues.

Comment: Because our drummer, keyboards and rhythm guitar are the same person, we record drums and synths and play them back for our live gigs as our backing track.

Comment: What do you use for the playback?

Comment: We run it direct from Cubase on a laptop, through stereo DI box into house PA, typically, but we have 4 or 5 potions in case of challenges

Comment: And we sync to the backing through our monitors

Comment: Interesting definition of 'live' :-)